# Power LED always stays on after shutting down the laptop

Tags: shutdown, power-management, dell-inspiron

I am using a Dell n5050 laptop, recently I noticed that I have a problem with my laptop. Namely, the power LED always stays on after shutting down the laptop.

I've found two options:

1. long press of the power switch will turn the LED off
2. remove the battery will also turn it off

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What OS is the laptop running? Is this the same as the front of your laptop (http://hotline.ua/img/tx/754/7546335.jpg)?

Answer (score 7):

This LED reflects the fact that your laptop is plugged into the power network. Unplug it and the LED will be switched off.

The battery charge continues after you shut down your laptop. The long press on the power button stops this charging

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering whether the **installed OS** isn't properly shutting the laptop down (ACPI) because the user is having to "press and hold" the power button or remove the battery (cutting the power supply). This is usually done to forcibly power off the machine if it freezes or doesn't (or can't) shutdown properly using ACPI. If the user has Windows 8 installed then its hybrid shutdown/hibernate may be a contributing factor.

A picture of a Dell n5050 (http://hotline.ua/img/tx/754/7546335.jpg) shows that there are separate LEDs for "powered on" and "charging".

**Charging LED**: Should only be on when a mains power source is connected (or possibly flashes when the battery requires charging).

**Power LED**: Should only be on when the laptop is powered on or should fade on/off when the laptop is in sleep or other low power state.

Answer (score -1):

You can do few troubleshooting steps:

1. Click on Start → right-click Computer → Device Manager
2. In Device Manager click the `+` sign before "Network adapters"
3. Under "Network adapters" right-click "Wireless adapter n1030", select Properties and go to the Power Management tab. Uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".
4. Under "Network adapters" right-click "RTL8111E Fast Ethernet controller", select Properties and go to the Power Management tab. Uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".
5. Go to Start menu → Control Panel
6. In Control Panel, go to "Hardware and Sound" → "Power Options"
7. Under Power Options click "Choose what the power buttons do"
8. Select the option that says "Shut down"
9. Also select "Choose what closing the lid does" and select "Shut down"