# Laptop not shutting down completely. Not fast startup (hardware?)

Tags: windows, laptop, hardware-failure, virus, shutdown

My Dell Inspiron N5050 does not shut down completely.  The screen shuts off completely and Windows seems to shutdown..
however, the power LED stays on (not the charging LED), the fan stays on, and I have to perform a hard shutdown to turn it off.  It doesn't shutdown on its own ever that I am aware of.  It won't even shutdown from the BIOS screen.

I called Dell support and it took them 1 1/2 hours to tell me that I have a boot sector virus.  I scanned the boot sector with an AVG Rescue disc (possibly Kapersky as well) to no avail.

What I have tried unsuccessfully:

- Turn off fast startup
- Scans
- Removing all drivers
- Flashing BIOS
- Reinstall Windows 8.1
- Install Windows 7
- Install Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials
- Rescue CDs
- Replace the 1TB HDD with 128GB SDD
- New CMOS

Nothing has brought me anywhere close to an answer to this problem.  I have opened the laptop several times.. could it be that I have damaged some hardware?  Also dual booted a Mac with the original Windows 8.1 disc with no problems.

My screen does not shut off when the lid closes.. maybe this is related?

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: How are you instructing the laptop to shut down from the BIOS setup screen?

Comment: Simply pressing the power button would normally shut the computer down from the BIOS menu screen.  To be more specific it was the screen to choose the startup drive.  Maybe thats not BIOS?

Comment: The screen at which you choose a boot device in all probability is still under control of the BIOS. Whatever the case, with no operating system yet stated I agree that a simple press of the power button should immediately and fully power down the system. That said, try disconnecting *every* non-essential component (e.g. the battery, hard drive, all but 1 stick of RAM, etc.) and try to repro the problem. If it persists you definitely have bad hardware, possibly the MB itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reseating the battery or other components?
It could be a problem with the CMOS battery.

Here is a similar question: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/480755/power-led-always-stays-on-after-shutting-down-the-laptop).

Comment: Thank you, I have already looked at this post.  The CMOS has been replaced within the past 5 months.  This problems happens whether or not I'm plugged in and the battery has been reseated many times.

Comment: This is beyond me. It seems like you've tried just about everything. I'm guessing there's some issue with hardware. My Dell laptop at work had problems as well. Today the Dell person came in and looked at it, apparently it needs a new motherboard and graphics card.